# How to list all mails in all folders in to a single view in Outlook 2007?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am used to Lotus Notes way of viewing all emails in a single view, so I can sort them easily or move them or archive these at will. My company uses outlook 2007, and to find any email using a search string, I now need to search individually in all folders.

is there a better way of doing so in Outlook 2007. I would not mind using any script for this.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your problem is to search mail from all your mails at a single point.

If yes, you can do that by clicking "All Mail Items" and then search the tag that you want. But this will not list any mails unless you try to search.